# Filtering date in Django Rest Framework (range between start and end date)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**models.py**

`date_created = models.DateTimeField()`

In frontend, I have two params like:

`date_created_start` and `date_created_end`.

What is the best approach to filter `date_created` and get objects created between `date_created_start` and `date_created_end`?

Can I add `date_created` to `filter_fields` and then:

`?date_created__gte=<date>&date_created__lte=<date>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user the field lookups [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#range)

```
Sample.objects.filter(date_created__range=[date_created_start, date_created_end])
```

or field lookups [gte and lte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#gte)

```
Sample.objects.filter(date_created__gte=date_created_start,
                      date_created__lte=date_created_end)
```